# python exec() raises SyntaxError exception when passing an object inside the string argument

Tags: python, syntax-error, exec, web3py, brownie

So I am currently trying to deploy my smart contract using a brownie script as shown in the code below:

```
from brownie import accounts, network
import sys

sys.path.append("../")
import globalVars

def main():

    import_str = "from {0} import {1}".format("brownie", globalVars.contractName)
    exec(import_str)

    network.connect('development')
    accounts.add()
    account = accounts[0]
   
    transactDetails = {'from' : account}
    prompt = f"contract_instance = {globalVars.contractName}.deploy( 
                         *globalVars.constructorInputs , {transactDetails} )"
    exec(prompt)

    return contract_instance
```

Meanwhile, when python interprets exec(prompt), it raises this error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    contract_instance = Voting.deploy( * globalVars.constructorInputs , {'from': <Account '0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871'>} )
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was expecting the smart contract to be deployed like in standard manner like in this code:

```
from brownie import accounts, network, Voting
import sys

sys.path.append("../")
import globalVars

def main():

    network.connect("development")
    accounts.add()
    account = accounts[0]
    print(globalVars.constructorInputs)
    contract_instance = Voting.deploy( * globalVars.constructorInputs ,  {'from' : account} )
    
    
    return contract_instance
```

I tried troubleshooting but could not find a solution, could someone please help!

Comment: `exec()` should be avoided. See chepner's answer for how to do so. On the other hand, you can use `contract_instance = eval(f'{...}').deploy(*..., transactDetails)`.

Comment: @InSync thank you so much bro, your alternative could be so helpful to me in further processes, xoxo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `exec` at all. Use something like

```
import brownie
import globalVars

def main():

    contract = getattr(brownie, globalVars.contractName)

    network.connect('development')
    accounts.add()
    account = accounts[0]
   
    transactDetails = {'from' : account}
    contract_instance = contract.deploy( 
                         *globalVars.constructorInputs , **transactDetails)

    return contract_instance
```

Comment: Thank you, your reply has helped, just one tiny remark:

I store my global variables in a python file called globalVars which is located between my flask directory and my brownie project, that is why I use:
import sys
sys.path.append("../")
import globalVars

inside my code, so that the target file could recognize which variables I am using.

Anyway thanks for the fast feedback!

Solved!